# Languages where the word for addict references submission

Tags: etymology

I noticed in Dutch the word for "addict" includes the word "slave". Namely "verslaafde" wherein "slaaf" is slave. One might say the word as a whole suggests enslavement.
I find this striking as addiction can be seen as a form of submission.

I've asked AI but could not find other languages that reference slave or submission in the word for addict.

I'm wondering if there are any.

Comment: You need to provide research. Don't you have a Dutch dictionary since you appear to be Dutch? Also, this is not linguistics, it's etymology.

Comment: @Lambie Etymology _is_ part of linguistics. There’s a restriction (that I don’t actually agree with, but it was decided on by the community) that questions of etymology are only considered on-topic here on this site if they deal with the systematicity of historical development and cognacy, so this would likely be considered off-topic – but that doesn’t mean etymology is non-linguistic, just that it’s not inherently on-topic here. (I would be more likely to consider it off-topic because it’s asking for an open-ended list of examples.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would say it the other way around. In any event, making a minimal effort is a good idea especially when the OP speaks Dutch and most of us do not.

Comment: Another example is Scottish Gaelic [tràill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tràill#Scottish_Gaelic), which means both ‘slave’ and ‘addict’. It was borrowed from Old Norse _þræll_ just like the now rather archaic English term _thrall_, also meaning a slave. And of course, even in regular English, we can describe someone as being ‘a slave to [something drug-like]’, which is essentially describing an addiction.

Comment: Lambie I've added some more information. I don't know what you mean in terms of research I've looked extensively on the topic online.

Comment: @KoertvanKleef Asking AI, which doesn't understand things in that way, isn't research.

Comment: It would obviously be more helpful to say what IS research instead of telling me what isn't. I literally said that I don't know what was meant. And I searched extensively online aside from AI.

Answer (score 4):

How about English? "Addict" is borrowed from Latin *addictus*, passive participle of *addīcō*, "deliver, surrender, enslave (a person to another person)".